# Order of operations with parenthesis and ||

Tags: php

I have an if condition, and for some reason, even with an empty timestamp (an empty string), my else condition is still executing.

```
if (($limit_by == 0 && $latest_timestamp < $historical_timestamp) || 
    empty($latest_timestamp)) {
    //stuff here
}
else {
    //other stuff
    $year = date("Y", $latest_timestamp);
}
```

So if `$latest_timestamp` is empty, I am still occasionally having the else condition trigger (which is causing 1969 dates because $latest_timestamp isn't set). I've also tried `!isset()` for the $latest_timestamp to test and see if that would help. Neither did.

Is there some order of operations thing I'm missing here that would cause the other two conditions to override the empty check? They should only be increasing the range of items that trigger the conditional, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Your `if` logic expression appears to be `false`. No one can tell you why unless you will dump values of that expression variables

Comment: Cannot reproduce. https://www.evernote.com/l/AAO6Tuwa_hdPT7PqPPeXUE14bCP4k-d4TJk

Comment: One of these two conditions `$limit_by == 0` or `$latest_timestamp < $historical_timestamp` conditions must not be true...

Comment: But if neither is true, and empty($latest_timestamp) is, I want the if block to execute.

Comment: *"even with an empty timestamp"* - as per what, db related? that could matter on what you would define as empty, or NULL or whatever. Default values in DB for timestamps as NULL `!=` empty.

Comment: Can't you simply figure out what the value of `latest_timestamp` and all the other variables is? That would make this a whole lot easier than a bunch of guesswork by strangers on the internet.

Comment: What's the format of your timestamp? Is it a [unix timestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) or perhaps one of the [`datetime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) formats here? Empty is a relative term. An empty timestamp could be like what _@ArunKrish_ described below, or it could be an empty string or it could simply be `NULL` as @Fred-ii- noted above...

Comment: By empty, I mean it is an empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there some order of operations thing I'm missing here that would cause the other two conditions to override the empty check?

**No.**

But you need to verify `$latest_timestamp` is set. Otherwise the condition `$latest_timestamp < $historical_timestamp` will always be true as it is cast to 0.

I would suggest adding `isset($latest_timestamp)` to your first condition, or better yet, taking advantage of [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) by moving the second condition to the front.

```
if (empty($latest_timestamp) 
    || ($limit_by == 0 && $latest_timestamp < $historical_timestamp))
```

Comment: Switching the empty check to the first condition made it work. That makes sense.

Comment: Yes, adding `isset()` to the first condition or swapping the order do the same thing. However, be sure read the link on short circuit evaluation to understand why.

Comment: I think you really only need one parenthesis before the `empty` statement

Comment: Sorry, I may be missing something. I understand the logic of moving the second condition to the front for short circuiting purposes, but if it evaluated to true in this case, would it not have evaluated to true the other way around. Do you mind explaining why this works and the OPs original code doesn't? Doesn't only one condition ever have to be true for the code within the `if` statement to execute?

Comment: Yeah, I understand the concept behind short-circuiting, but I am curious like War10ck why this would work and my other code was not evaluating the way I wanted it to.

Comment: @War10ck, I can not without knowing their exact input. Regardless, this order communicates intent better and guards against the greater than comparison when `$latest_timestamp` is empty.

Comment: Fair enough. It definitely makes more sense to do it this way any how. Thanks for sharing. +1

Answer (score 1):

I advise you first check emptiness of `$latest_timestamp` and only then - check if it's less than other timestamps. `cause empty values in comparison with other timestamp will be converted to 0, I suppose, and your first condition can be evaluated to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking with

```
$latest_timestamp == '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

instead of checking empty($latest_timestamp). Because the default empty timestamp value is '0000-00-00 00:00:00'